# Symfony2 Multiple Projects

Tags: php, symfony

Can you direct me to some tutorials or helpful information regarding Symfony2 and common components among similar projects? I have two projects that will use a tremendous amount of the same code (mostly backend logic/user handling/checkouts), but there will be quite a different in the frontend templates, display and functionality.

Currently I have three folders with symlinks (Project 1, Project 2, and Symfony Base). Is this the best setup? Recommendations for doing it better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony 2 Bundles are what you want here. Wrap up all the stuff you want to share between projects in a bundle installed in to both - then build the project specific UI on top of it.

Would recommend on the Symfony 2 docs: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/bundles/index.html

Comment: For development, composer would slow down the workflow a lot. Also the IDE wont recognise a lot of the used settings when you keep the bundles developed seperatly